# Git push remote work but no changes visible

Tags: deployment, gunicorn, git-push, supervisord, git-remote

I am currently facing a little problem with git when pushing to my remote server.

Everything works fine on local server, it commit successfully and so do push to my remote repo. Git show master and git show remote-repo/master show the commits modifications done so everything should normally work.

Still when accessing my website nothing has changed. The files simply haven't changed. The remote repo is a bare one, my app is built with Flask, Gunicorn and I use supervisor to manage it. I tried to change git remote path to a new directory created with copy of my files in it, restart supervisor and gunicorn, restart my server, but nothing changed. What is strange is that first push worked. I'd net on a problem of directory structure or oath, still everything is the same. Except that my files are stores in one more directory than local. But i tried to copy files in the upper directory and it did not change anything.

I am kinda lost now and would be grateful for decades for any help or clues about this problem.

Thanks !!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok so i've got it working finally ! To do so i init another --bare repo and created a folder for website files. Then, in the bare repo, add to /hooks folder a post-receive SH/script file to check-out files when push received from bare directory to the one for website files. I edited  supervisor conf and nginx one, reloaded and restarted all. it's okay now !

Answer (score 0):

Still a little confused on your set up. You develop on local and push to a server. Does the server have the bare repo or does the server hosting the website have the bare repo?

When you push to a bare that doesn't mean the working tree has changed since bare is just a bare repo- no working tree. If this is the case you have to follow these steps:

```
1. push from local to server that contains bare
2. pull from the remote bare location from the production server
         (the one that contains the website)
3. restart apache or whatever you have
```

Hope this helps. Please let me know if I am on the right track.

Comment: Thank you so much for such a rapid answer ! In facts my bare repo is in the root of my website folder, and the website files served are in a subdirectory.  So tree would be /website that contains bare repo and /website/website_files. I may try to pull as you say to see if it works.

Comment: Yeah so when in the /website/. you would do a git clone from 1 directory up. Or if the files are already there you would do a pull.

Comment: Ok  I come back from my experiments and nothing worked out. I tried git pull in my local repo and in my remote repo and it shows that everything is up-to-date. I also tried git show on the local and remote, and the current commit are the good one (the latest) I tried git branch -v to check if the branch is the good one and still everything's perfect. Still, the modifications made in the commits doesn't appear in the files and so on the website. I am getting headaches, and found no solutions on SO or Google yet. Still searching though. I am starting to think I will have to reset everything :(